# Wrong serialization of timedate in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#

In my app, I am using MVC architecture. My controller returns data about the client such as birthdate. Client info is converted into a JSON object and passed to view.

Now the problem is my DateTime field is acting little strange. My date passed from the view is correct:

> {29.07.1978 0:00:00}

After conversion to json it is:

> /Date(270511200000)/

Now comes the strange part - it returns

> 28.07.1978

When I try to look for more detail by converting the json date to Date myself by this:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(self.FormData.Person.BirthDate().substr(6)));
```

I get

> Fri Jul 28 1978 23:00:00 GMT+0100

But when I enter some newer Date - for example, 1.1.2000, I get a correct date of 1.1.2000.

For some other dates, I'm getting

> Fri Jul 28 1959 22:00:00 GMT+0200

Any idea why is this happening? My timezone is GMT+1.

Thanks a lot for any input :)

Comment: Thats not strange. 29.07.1978 0:00:00 *Zulu* was on the 28.07. at your local timezone.

Comment: @JonasWilms - Thanks, but I dont understand why Im getting correct results for dates from 1980+

Comment: Cause summer time was introduced in your country in 1979 https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/czech-republic/prague

Answer (score 0):

As per Jonas Wilms answer below - `

> Cause summer time was introduced in your country in 1979
>   timeanddate.com/time/zone/czech-republic/prague

What fixed this for me was

```
if (birthYear <= 1979) {
                if (self.FormData.Person.BirthDate() != null) {
                    self.FormData.Person.BirthDate(moment(self.FormData.Person.BirthDate()).utcOffset(2).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
                }
            }
            else {
                if (self.FormData.Person.BirthDate() != null) {
                    self.FormData.Person.BirthDate(moment(self.FormData.Person.BirthDate()).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
                }
            }
```